Mixed Model with multiple DVs and two time points
I'm doing a study with the following design:

2 groups (between)
2 time points (within)
10 scenarios (within)
5 DVs (continuous)

Participants of both groups experience the 10 scenarios at both time points. I want to check if people perform better in the DVs in time point 2 compared to time point 1. The effect should be bigger in the experimental group than in the control group.
I initially thought about doing a three-way repeated Measures ANOVA for each of the DVs.
However, I also thought about the possibility to do a mixed model with multiple DVs. I'm a bit unsure on whether it is ok to do a mixed model with only 2 time points, since all the examples are with more than 2 time points and I've seen mixed opinions on this.
In this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bGG02Jsjyc&pp=ygULI21peGVkbW9kZWw%3D
it is said that when you only have 2 measurements on the same subject the mixed model with random intercepts will result in the exact same p-value as the rmANOVA but only if the repeated measurements have a positive correlation since linear mixed models assume that the observations within a cluster are positively related.
In my case I would have 20 measurements per subject (2 time points x 10 scenarios), so I'm not sure, if this actually applies. I expect some DVs to show positive correlation between time points and some to have a negative correlation.
In another forum post I've read that having only 2 time points is fine, and to define it as fixed effect. Makes sense to me.
I just want to make sure that I'm not on the wrong path here. Is it ok to do a mixed model with only 2 time points, only categorial IVs and several DVs?
Thanks

Welcome to the site, @Anna! Are you using R or something else. I am working on an answer and wanted to provide some syntax for you to make it more helpful.

Hi Erik, thanks for your reply! Yes I'm using R

Hey @ErikRuzek :) I've had a think about this question but haven't come up with an answer yet - curious to know if you've made any headway with it ? I guess MCMCglmm and stan (or other Bayesian packages like JAGS that have R front-ends) could be possibilities ?

@RobertLong, I gave it a go. Please feel free to comment or add an additional answer if you have other thoughts!

There are a couple of issues you raise. Let's start with the simpler one and then move to the more complex one.

Repeated measures ANOVA vs. mixed models. With balanced data (>= 2 time points), no missing data, and a positive ICC, these will give you equivalent p-values for the tests of fixed effects (factors in your case). The mixed model is way more flexible, however, and at this point should be the default for most analyses (something people have been saying since the early 2000s).

Assuming you have your data in a long or stacked format with multiple rows per participant, the lme4 syntax for a single DV model that is most like RM-ANOVA would be lmer(DV1 ~ time*group + scenario + (1 | participant)). This gives you the test of whether participants improve at t2 via the time*group interaction. You can use handy packages such as marginaleffects or ggeffects to plot the interaction based on the model. It is not clear to me how you think about scenario. In this formulation, it is simply a covariate.*

Multivariate approaches. You have 5 DVs, which is a lot. A multivariate approach to this would help to deal with any concern that the DVs are correlated. In general, multivariate models can increase the power to detect effects and help to control the error rate. See this excellent CV discussion thread. The challenge is that you have multilevel data, and while you can trick nlme into multivariate mixed effects, I think it will struggle to deal with 5 DVs. As @Robert Long alludes to, you probably need to go Bayesian to handle this many DVs. Personally, I'd probably use brms. See here. You will need to install STAN if you haven't already (see here). Another possibility is to use lavaan. It should be possible, combining the multilevel syntax with the multivariate syntax, but I haven't done it myself.

*The issue of how to handle scenario is potentially quite interesting. Because all subjects were exposed to all scenarios, the data is fully crossed. Ignoring the issue of MANOVA vs mixed models, the scenarios are a source of variance in the DV that must be accounted for in some way. One possibility is to treat them as a separate random intercept along with participant random intercept. In R syntax, lmer(DV1 ~ time*group + (1|scenario) + (1|participant)). Scenario can also be treated as a non-varying (fixed) intercept, which is the approach I used above and would be appropriate if the scenarios were of little to no substantive interest.

Thanks for your detailed explanation! Indeed I do struggle with the scenarios. I'm doing a driving simulator study with different scenarios in which I measure the DVs. These DVs and scenarios can be clustered in speed (scenarios where I'm interested in mean & SD of speed); acceleration (scenarios where I'm interested in different acceleration parameters) and deceleration (scenarios where I'm interested in different deceleration parameters). Thus I'm not interested in all of the DVs in all of the scenarios. But I figured, if I take scenarios as variable in my model, I have to report everything.

Looks very good to me Erik (+1). I might just add that the reason for going Bayesian doesn't have anything (directly) to do with Bayesian vs Frequentist. Rather it's simply that these Bayesian packages are much more flexible in what they can model than most frequentist software.  Also, those are terrific links -  I don't think I have seen most of them before !  And lavaan is a good call too :)

@Anna, you are welcome! With regard to scenarios, you might consider looking at a subset of them or some combination of a subset of the DVs with a subset of the scenarios. You already have a lot going on here. The degree to which you can simplify it a bit will make it easier for both you and your audience.
